# vertical scrollbar in Itemselector in extJs

Tags: extjs4, itemselector

I am using extJs 4.0. 
I am dynamically loading the data  in item selector from the store. The no. of Values in item selector will increase in future.I want a vertical scrollbar in lefthandside of the item selector. I googled but didn't find any solution. If any one can please help and suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemSelector is nothing but the combination of two Multiselector and some buttons.
So i added a property in Multiselector.Js
autoScroll: true
and also set the height property in ItemSelector.js 
height: me.height
So that now i can set the height of my itemSelector and Scroll bar is also working perfect.